# Return multiple columns from datarow for a textbox control after passing the dataset to an array (VB.Net, ASP.NET, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, web-applications

I have a situation that I've been working for a few hours - I feel like there is something really obvious here but I'm missing it.  I've never worked in a development environment as abastracted as this, so I'm sure that's part of it.  Any assistance/advice would be gratefully welcomed.

- **The product:** A web app
- **The environment:**

  ~ ***Database/back end;*** SQL Server Management Studio, SQL Server 2008 R2

  ~ ***Interfaces/front end;*** ASPX pages, SharePoint 2010

  ~ ***Languages, Development;*** Visual Studio 2010, VB.Net, JavaScript, HTML, SQL, Ajax, jQuery

  ~ ***Misc;*** Web parts, Update panels, etc
- **The Task & Issue:**

Update the code for a textbox on an aspx.cs that shows an org code with an org name (currently shows name only).  The textbox currently shows the org name.  The code calls a stored procedure from SQL Server which passes in the columns and data needed.

So far I have been able to update the code so that you can start to type in an org code or the name of an org and a list of orgs will populate in a dropdown fashion.  Whether an org code or name is used, only the org name shows in the list and resulting selection.  I need it to show the org code and the name.

The code I have thus far is this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;

using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using IDE_Utility.DBConnection;

namespace ORG40.Layouts.ORG40
{
    public partial class OrganizationSearch : LayoutsPageBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GetCompleteList(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataSet DS = new DataSet();

            SqlParameter sqlParamComp = new SqlParameter();
            sqlParamComp.ParameterName = "@oName";
            sqlParamComp.DbType = DbType.String;
            sqlParamComp.Value = "%" + OrganizationName.Text + "%";

            SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[]{
                new SqlParameter("@orgCode", DBNull.Value),                
                sqlParamComp
            };

            DS = DBConnection.GetDataSet("getL_Organization", CommandType.StoredProcedure, sqlParams);
            GridView1.DataSource = DS;
            GridView1.DataBind();



        }
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string[] getNames(string prefixText, int count)
        {
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            SqlParameter sqlParamComp = new SqlParameter();
            sqlParamComp.ParameterName = "@oName";
            sqlParamComp.DbType = DbType.String;
            sqlParamComp.Value = "%" + prefixText + "%";

            SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[]{
                new SqlParameter("@orgCode", DBNull.Value),                
                sqlParamComp
            };

            DS = DBConnection.GetDataSet("getL_Organization", CommandType.StoredProcedure, sqlParams);


            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
            Dt = DS.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, new string[] {"OrgCode", "Name"});
            DataRow[] Dr = new DataRow[Dt.Rows.Count];
            Dt.Rows.CopyTo(Dr, 0);
            return Array.ConvertAll(Dr, new Converter<DataRow, String>(DataRowToString));

        }

        public static string DataRowToString(DataRow pDr)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(pDr["OrgCode" "Name"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like the answer lies somewhere between the line:

`Dt = DS.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable(true, new string[] {"OrgCode", "Name"});`

And return line from the array:

`return Convert.ToString(pDr["OrgCode" "Name"].ToString());`

I'm thinking my issue is in trying to display the org code from that last line.  If I just use "Name" it works, but every time I modify it the textbox displays nothing, or the code is in error.

My latest thoughts are regarding the last line of code - I realize that the `return Convert.ToString(pDr["OrgCode" "Name"]` is incorrect syntax - I had been trying to determine how to properly account for multiple columns in `["OrgCode" "Name"]`.

If there are any thoughts or ideas out there I would be most appreciative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question at the ASP.NET forums as well and got the answer there.  The last line I was struggling with:

```
return Convert.ToString(pDr["OrgCode" "Name"].ToString());
```

was set to:

```
return (Convert.ToString(pDr["OrgCode"]) + " " + Convert.ToString(pDr["Name"]));
```

Worked like a champ!  Thanks to everyone who reviewed this question!